# Cloning dual boot drive

Tags: dual-boot, dd

I would like to make an exact copy of my old 250 gb HDD (not installed), and clone to a new 240 gb SSD (installed).

The old HDD is dual booted with equal partition scheme, rEFIt booting OSX Snow Leopard/Ubuntu 12.10.

Would I be better off cloning to an external drive then restoring the image from external to internal drive (requiring internal drive swap)? Or is there a way I could boot from the old HDD via usb then format and restore the installed SSD with the HDD image from within disk utility? The machine is a 2009 macbook with OSX Mavericks installed.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The "simplest" way to clone one drive to another in your scenario.

is to boot of an ubuntu live cd is to have both drives connected in your computer and booting of a usb stick.

Once the live cd has started
In the terminal type:

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

check witch drive is the new and witch is the old one

it should be  /dev/sda , /dev/sdb   (you should be able to tell by checking the size reported for each drive which is wich)

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=1024
```

where in my example sda is the original drive you want to copy FROM
and sdb is the new drive you want to copy TO.

This will take a while since it will copy the ENTIRE drive, even if data isn't being used

This procedure is operating system agnostic meaning that it will always work no matter what filesystem(s) or partitions exist on the original drive.

I've used this to in the simplest possible way move my tripple boot configuration (Windows 7, OsX, Ubuntu) to a new bigger SSD disk.

In your scenario though there is ONE problem.
your source drive is bigger then your destination drive.
Since dd will just read everything from drive a and copy it to drive b it will fail to copy all data.

Hence you need to re size your original drives last partition to be a bit smaller than your new HD.

If it is the OSX partition that occupies the last space on your drive use diskutil in osX to shrink it.

if it is the Windows partition, you can use gparted since it has resize support for NTFS.

Id shrink it 5-10gig or so to get some margins

In another scenario (perhaps just Ubuntu / Windows) i would recommend using [clonezilla]
but the OSX filesystem HFS is porly supported in Linux[1](http://clonezilla.org/).

Comment: this is proving to be too difficult an option for what I need to accomplish. Thank you for your help nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

The following came from cyberciti's website and seems applicable (skim down but the full read is informative so I'm copying it all)

To copy MBR simply use the `dd` command. The `dd` command works under all
Linux distros and other UNIX like operating systems too. A master boot
record (MBR) is the 512-byte boot sector that is the first sector of a
partitioned data storage device of a hard disk.

> MBR Total Size 
>   446 + 64 + 2 = 512 
>   Where, 
>   446 bytes - Bootstrap. 
>   64 bytes - Partition table. 
>   2 bytes - Signature. 
>   512 vs 446 Bytes

Use 446 bytes to overwrite or restore your `/dev/XYZ MBR` boot code only with the contents
of `$mbr.backup.file`.

Use 512 bytes to overwrite or restore your `/dev/XYZ`, the full MBR (which contains both
boot code and the drive's partition table) with the contents of `$mbr.backup.file`.

The `dd` command to copy the MBR (identically sized partitions only) is as follows:

`dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1`

The above command will copy 512 bytes (MBR) from sda to the sdb disk. This will only work if both discs have identically sized partitions.

`dd` command for two discs with different size partitions:

`dd if=/dev/sda of=/tmp/mbrsda.bak bs=512 count=1`

Now to restore the image to any sdb:

`dd if=/tmp/mbrsda.bak of=/dev/sdb bs=446 count=1`

The above commands will preserve the partitioning schema.

The Linux `sfdisk` command can make a backup of the primary and extended partition table as
follows. It creates a file that can be read in a text editor, or this file can be used by `sfdisk` to restore the primary/extended partition table. To back up the partition table in `/dev/sda`, enter:

`sfdisk -d /dev/sda > /tmp/sda.bak`

To restore, enter:

`sfdisk /dev/sda < /tmp/sda.bak`

The above command will restore extended partitions.

Task: Backup the MBR and Extended Partitions Schema. To backup the `/dev/sda` MBR, enter:

`dd if=/dev/sda of=/tmp/backup-sda.mbr bs=512 count=1`

Next, backup the entries of the extended partitions:

`sfdisk -d /dev/sda > /tmp/backup-sda.sfdisk`

Copy `/tmp/backup-sda.sfdisk` and `/tmp/backup-sda.mbr` to an USB pen or somewhere else safe
over the network, based as server.

Task: Restore MBR and the Extended Partitions Schema. To restore the MBR and the extended partitions copy the backup files from a backup media and enter:

`dd if=backup-sda.mbr of=/dev/sda`

`sfdisk /dev/sda < backup-sda.sfdisk`