# Copy hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, backup, copy

How do I go about coping my entire hard drive, which only has Ubuntu on it? It would be copied to an exterior hard drive, before I try the repair disk or have to wipe and reinstall. I don't want to lose anything else.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate have a look at the answere [here][1]


  [1]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/388932/cloning-dual-boot-drive/388951#388951

Answer (score 2):

Install Clonezilla from Ubuntu Software Center or run

```
sudo apt-get install clonezilla
```

Then run

```
sudo clonezilla
```

It will have a CLI menu to copy full disk or partitions to an external drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can backup your entire hard drive in many different ways, including cp, clonezilla, rsync, tar ...

As I admire functionality of clonezilla, I sometimes prefer rsync because it allows you immediate access to your files on backup storage, in your case external hard drive. It will have exactly same directory structure and you may just browse folders, files and search in them. Also your next backup may just be a difference, rsync allows you to rewrite just changed files so you will save enormous amount of computer resources and time.

```
$ sudo rsync -aAXHvP --exclude='/dev/*' --exclude='/proc/*' --exclude ='/sys/*' --exclude='/media/*' --exclude='run/' --exclude='/mnt/*' /* /media/external-hard-drive
```

For more information on individual rsync options see `man rsync`.

---

Why these excludes, I will borrow these lines from Ubuntu Community Wiki:

*... you will need to add several more --exclude= arguments to avoid filesystems you do not want. These would be /proc, /sys, /mnt, /media, /run and /dev directories in root. /proc and /sys are virtual filesystems that provide windows into variables of the running kernel, so you do not want to try and backup or restore them. /dev is a tmpfs whose contents are created and deleted dynamically by udev, so you also do not want to backup or restore it. Likewise, /run is a tmpfs that holds variables about the running system that do not need backed up.*

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR

Comment: Thanks for all the great advice. Going on line doesn't do me any good since I can't. That why I have use repair disk or wipe and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Clonezilla is great, but if you ever need to restore to a smaller partition it becomes a pain. I prefer to use [fsarchiver](http://www.fsarchiver.org/Main_Page), which quickly creates very compressed backups that can be deployed anywhere you need them. There's a neat PDF with a recommended backup model found here: https://github.com/issmirnov/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/fsarchiver/backup-ver2.pdf

The usage is very simple. To backup, you do `sudo fsarchiver savefs -vj4z5 /media/BACKUP_DRIVE/backup.fsa /dev/sdXy`. Restoring is trivial as well.

You can even use it to perform backups of LVM systems while running using snapshots.

More docs here can be found here: `http://www.fsarchiver.org/QuickStart`

Hope this helps!